# Assigning an array variable to a pointer of same data type in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, pointers

IN the following C++ snippet, is a=b assigment possible ??:

```
unsigned int * a;
D3DCOLOR b[16];
a=(unsigned int)b;
```

Will this assignment copy all the elements of b array to a? Is the typecast fine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, it should have been:

```
a = (unsigned int *)b; // note the *
```

More importantly, this just makes `a` *point to* contents of `b`, and it does **not** copy it. If you want to copy arrays, you have to do it explicitly, for example with a `for` loop or `std::copy`, that is if you don't want to go with classes and stuff.

Side note: to copy into `a`, you need memory for `a`! You can do it either on the stack:

```
unsigned int a[16]; // 16 is an example
```

or dynamically (for example with `new`).

Comment: And also, before you copy into what is pointed to by `a`, allocate some memory and have `a` point to it.

Comment: Use `std::copy` to copy objects, whether or not you "go with classes and stuff".

Comment: To allocate memory of 16 elemnts for *a. Is this correct?                 a = new unsigned int[16]; ??   Am I correct ?  I am from C# background. So always get confused with C++ syntaxes and rules. Sorry. PLz let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You allocate 16 elements and have `a` point to it (Think of `new` as building a house and `a` as a piece of paper to write its address. `*a` would be the house itself). That is correct, `a = new unsigned int [16];` should do the trick (although like I said if you don't need to pass it around just `unsigned int a[16];` will suffice). Also remember that whatever array you `new`, you must later `delete[]` it when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will not work, with a pointer you get access to the same memory as the object you point it to.
What do you want to do, exactly? From your code, I'd guess that the array you have is a bit array and you want the corresponding unsigned integer. 
In that case, do something like this:

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned int length = 16;
D3DCOLOR b[length];
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  a |=  b[(length-1) - i] << i;
}
```

This will take each bit, shift it by the requisite amount and then write it to a. Take a look at bit operations in c / c++ if you want to know more.

(Note: This code assumes big endian bit order).

Comment: there is a thing called a `KISS` principle... and it applies to your answer. `KISS` unfolds to `Keep It Simple, S...` (am trying to replace the last S to unfold into something diff, but that's the way I first read it years ago, and nothing else seems to fit. Didn't mean to offend)

Comment: I posted my answer because at the moment I don't know another way to fit an array of 16 objects into an unsigned int than to treat the objects as bits. It is probably too much of a guess though, so I understand where you are coming from.

Comment: I think the author wanted for a to be of type `unsigned int *` -- pointer! Question is a bit unclear, I admit, but the title of the question makes it very clear, pointer of the same type. No hurry, you'll get your rep, don't need to answer any Q that you know _something_ about -- in a few days, you'll find a Q that looks like it was written just for you to answer ;)